# Is there a word that describes something that is invisible when it is alone but in numbers it is visible?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or slang word that can be used to describe something that is invisible on its own and in numbers it is visible?

For example:

> One bacterium is hard to see (invisible to the naked eye) but when there is a huge population of bacteria it can be seen (visible to the naked eye)

I used the concept of bacteria to further my point but I don't necessarily mean microscopic organisms.

Edit:

Another example:

> One star is hard to see from a distance but when you look at a galaxy (collection of stars) from the same distance visibility is significantly increased.

The use of the word would be in terms of population.

An individual alone in a population vs a large group in a population.

Comment: *Microscopic* comes to min.

Comment: Oops! Missing a *d* there.

Comment: I used the concept of bacteria to further my point but I don't necessarily mean microscopic organisms.

Comment: Your example is explaining the concept, but it doesn't really tell me how you want to use the word. Can you provide a sentence of how your hypothetical word would be used?

Comment: @Fendec you can also add an other example using a star and a galaxy at a same distance.

Comment: Voting to close, since asker seems unresponsive to requests to update the question with additional information. That said, consider ***infinitesimal***, used in mathematics to refer to a vanishingly small quantity, yet when aggregated (with an integral) yields a measurable value.

Comment: Does it need to have a physical analogy? Or would something along the lines of *silent majority* or *face in a crowd* convey the meaning?

Comment: Such a word, if it existed, would be, as they say, a much needed gap in the lexicon. A single word for such a complex concept is not necessary; simply say 'undetectable when alone but visible in groups'.

Comment: Also suggesting your concept is the word *atomic* (see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atomic). Atoms are invisible on their own, but become visible in large aggregates. However, in order for that meaning to come through, the phrasing would have to be just right; the word doesn't evoke it automatically.

Comment: some suggestions:  When x occurs x "surfaces and becomes apparent"  or "becomes visible" "surfaces" synonyms: appears, materializes; comes into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your descriptions, the word "**gestalt**" (borrowed from German - meaning "greater pattern" or "sum of it's individual parts") would seem to come close in meaning.

The individual components (single stars), being relatively unnoticeable alone, become very noticeable within the gestalt of a galaxy.

The individual components (single bacteria), being relatively unnoticeable alone, become quite visible in a visible gestalt forming bacterial colonies.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gestalt

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a word for that, not in English anyway. It's up to you to describe the concept elegantly, which you do. Your examples are very good. Something that is visible only in numbers . . .